# Shift least significant digit out of hex sequence in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, integer, hex, logical-operators

I am currently trying to write something which adjusts the blue values in a 6-digit hex code (it takes it's hex code from an object 'colour' in a superior scope).

The hex code supplied by colours.chosen would be undefined if not yet set or in the format `"#hhhhhh"`:

```
//alter hex code value of current set colour
function hexIncrement()
{
  if (colours.chosen == undefined)
  { throw new Error("Trying to alter hex colour code in 'colours' object but this value has not yet been set"); }

  else if (!(/^\s*#\w{6}\s*$/.test(colours.chosen)))
  { throw new Error("'colours.chosen' object attribute does not translate appropriately to a hex value, meaning incorrect");  }

  let pre = colours.chosen.slice(1,5);
  let post = colours.chosen.slice(5, 7);

  post = parseInt(post, 16) + 0x11;
  console.log("added val is", post.toString(16));

  /*if the resultant number exceeds two hex digits 0xFF, then LSR 16 places (computer reads as binary representation) to eliminate extraneous digit*/
  if (post > 0xFF)
  {
    post = 16 >> post;
    console.log("Shifted hex number is: ", post);
  }

  post = post.toString(16);

  while (post.length < 2)
  {
    post += "0";
  }

  //output number in written hex format
  colours.chosen = "#" + pre.toString(16) + post.toString(16);
}
```

I understand this could easily be achieved by detecting the length of the hex digit sequence and removing the last digit via string slice, however I'd like to be able to do it in numerical fashion. My ideal result would be that the least significant digit is simply removed.

However, the result of `post = 16>>post` is 0, how can this be?

p.s: it works on js.do for me, just not my Chrome extension script

Comment: Yeah sure, if it is `0xEF` in then in adding `0x11` in addition of the hex values I get `100`. As such I would want the 'out' to be `0x10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`>>` shifts binary digits, so shifting `post >> 16` is a lot more than you want if you just need to remove the last digit. You want to take the floor of *dividing* by 16, which would be `post >> 4` (`16 == 2 ** 4`)

```js
let n = parseInt("ffee11", 16)
n = n >> 4
console.log(n.toString(16))

let n2 = 0xaabbcc
n2 = n2 >> 4
console.log(n2.toString(16))

// or divide
let n3 = 0xABFF12
let shifted = Math.floor(n3 / 16).toString(16)
console.log(shifted)
```

Comment: Thankyou, definitely a rookie error on my part not recognising I need to shift 4, but I didn't know about math.floor also so this  question has been helpful in 2 ways!